# Restart httpd from PHP, echo page before dying

Tags: php

So here's a little nut to crack. I have this webpage that does a very large set of tasks, and at the end, it restarts httpd to reload the new httpd.conf it just edited.

- There's no problem with this, but I would like to display a result before the server dies and restarts.
- The reason for this is that I originally made a js button that would execute the script, then replace the contents of a div with "Wait..." , and when the script ends, it fills the div with the content of the php file, in our case, "Finished." .
- Since I added the restart at the end, it just stays waiting.

I found the flush method and tried as follows, but no dice

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
echo "Finished.";
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_end_flush();
mysqli_close($conn);
$cmd= 'sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart';
exec($cmd);
exit();
```

edit:: some more info

Now I think the issue is not the php itself but the javascript. It looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("infocr").innerHTML = "Wait...";
$.post("create.php", {
user: targetuser
}
, function(datacr) {
document.getElementById("infocr").innerHTML = "datacr";
$('#csf')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
wait=1;
setTimeout(function(){wait=0;}, 5000);
});
```

The stuff between the brackets is never called because the php file never actually "ends". Can you suggest any workarounds for this? The 5 sec timer is to prevent the button from being spammed

Comment: Restart Apache with `graceful`, not a brute force `restart`.

Comment: @deceze worked beautifully. This is great, thanks. Post a complete answer so I can mark it

Comment: Just `apachectl graceful` should do.

Answer (score 2):

You can echo everything you want before restarting httpd. After that your php code will not be executed any more because httpd service is temporarily down.
A solution is to check a certain url with JavaScript `setInterval()` function to check if httpd is running again, and when you get a response, you can show a message that httpd restarted successfully.

Comment: I have a couple of problems with this tho. The server restarts almost instantly, how would I make show the check is not executed before the restart? Since the rr is so fast, I doubt I can catch a 404 error to tell JS it's offline and then online

Comment: Well, you can first wait for a couple of seconds and then start checking a url. The url should for example return a json response with status = ok